# Does a continuous, nondecreasing and positive real function commute with lim suplim sup of bounded sequences?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is satisfied $\limsup_{n→∞}f(a_n)=f(\limsup_{n→∞}a_n)$ for a continuous, nondecreasing and positive real function $f$ and real sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one direction:

Let $L = \limsup a_n$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exist infinitely many $n$ with the property that $a_n > L - \epsilon$. Since $f$ is nondecreasing,  there exist infinitely many $n$ with the property that $f(a_n) \ge f( L - \epsilon)$. Thus $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) \ge f(L - \epsilon).$$ Now use the continuity of $f$ to deduce $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) \ge f(L).$$

The other direction is similar. If $\epsilon > 0$ then $a_n < L + \epsilon$ for all but (at most) finitely many $n$.

Comment: Actually is the proposition remains true as long as $f$ continuous at $\text{lim}\ \text{sup}\ a_n$ and $(a_n)$ bounded above?

Comment: if $a_n=(-1)^n$ and taking $f(x)=1-x$ it is not true.

Comment: yeah I missed out that point but shall it be positive and continuous everywhere?